# Can't ping port 80 outside of docker container - recv failure - connection reset by peer

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm creating a react app in a docker container. More specifically, it contains much more than that, but I'm stuck on the react/nginx :80 being exposed outside the container. I don't seem to have this problem when I use another port like 3000 or 8080.

`git cone https://chrisconnors@bitbucket.org/chrisconnors/mndspn.git`

Then I just build the `frontend` with
`docker-compose up --build -d frontend`

After it's running, I can hit `0.0.0.0:80` in the container itself.

```
/ # wget 0.0.0.0:80
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:80 (0.0.0.0:80)
index.html           100% |******************************************|   548   0:00:00 ETA
```

However, when i hit that in the browser or curl from my terminal (outside the container), I get this error:

```
:~/src/mndspn$ curl --trace-ascii dump.txt 0.0.0.0:80
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
:~/src/mndspn$ cat dump.txt 
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: 0.0.0.0:80/
== Info:   Trying 0.0.0.0...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 71 bytes (0x47)
0000: GET / HTTP/1.1
0010: Host: 0.0.0.0
001f: User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
0038: Accept: */*
0045: 
== Info: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
== Info: stopped the pause stream!
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Can you show the ouput of the `docker ps` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the docker compose file that you might be using, Port 80 is not exposed in `frontend` service.

https://bitbucket.org/chrisconnors/mndspn/src/4724d5c4a3d67fad9e2e7d84f2ec3916e75360f7/docker-compose.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#docker-compose.yml-39

Uncomment the ports line {Line 39-40}

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

Start the container again using docker-compose and you should be able to access the application.

Comment: Thanks!

I thought I had already done that and was having issues with port 80 already being used and various other issues with it not working on :80.


I changed the following to ALL use or expose port 80
- docker-compose.yml
- frontend/Dockerfile
- frontend/nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

Connection Reset to a Docker container usually indicates that you've defined a port mapping for the container that does not point to an application.

So, if you've defined a mapping of 80:80, check that your process inside the docker instance is in fact running on port 80 (netstat -an|grep LISTEN).

Ensure you have the option -p 80:80 in your `docker run` command

Comment: container
```/ # netstat -an|grep LISTEN | grep tcp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39855        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
```
\n
laptop:
```root     29137  0.0  0.0   8512  3568 ?        Sl   22:49   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 192.168.176.2 -container-port 80
```

Comment: Also, I'm running with `docker-compose`, not `docker` directly.